# Laravel model eloquent

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent, model

Hello I have a problem with model eloquent in Laravel. How I can change this

```
SELECT *, CAST(`end` AS int) FROM `Punishments` WHERE (`PunishmentType` = :ban OR `PunishmentType` = :ipBan OR `PunishmentType` = :tempBan OR `PunishmentType` = :tempIpBan) AND (`end` > :now OR `end` = -1) ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT :limit OFFSET :offset
```

To this

```
protected Ban $ban;

public function __construct(Ban $ban)
{
    $this->ban = $ban;
}

public function getAllBans()
{
    return $this->ban
        ->where('PunishmentType', '=', 'BAN')
        ->where('PunishmentType', '=', 'IP_BAN')
        ->where('PunishmentType', '=', 'TEMP_BAN')
        ->where('PunishmentType', '=', 'TEMP_IP_BAN')
        ->where('end', '=', -1)
        ->orWhere('end', '>', time())
        ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
        ->paginate(20);
}
```

This doesn't work :(

```
->where('end', '=', -1)
->orWhere('end', '>', time())
```

Comment: Use `orWhere` for the PunishmentTypes? (PunishmentType can't be `'BAN'` and `'IP_BAN'` at the same time)

Comment: Yeah, but I don't know how I can do 'or' in eloquent

Comment: You're using `->orWhere('end', '>', time())` already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like the following:

```php
    return $this->ban
        ->whereIn('PunishmentType', ['BAN', 'IP_BAN', 'TEMP_BAN', 'TEMP_IP_BAN'])
        ->where(function($query) {
            $query->where('end', '>', time())
            orWhere('end', -1);
        })
        ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
        ->paginate(20);
```

Comment: Items for which the end date is two weeks ago are still displayed. Could this have something to do with the timestamp in the database being 13 digits?

Comment: Yes. Problem is 13 digits in 'end'. When I add time().'000' problem isn't be